# Looking for the next "Daylight Saving Time" using the Windows registery

Tags: c++, timezone, borland-c++

Looking for the next "Daylight Saving Time" using the Windows registry.

I have to use an old version of Borland C++.

Idea from [Daylight Saving Time change with an absolute date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575386/daylight-saving-time-change-with-an-absolute-date)

The "W. Europe Standard Time" in the registry says that the "Daylight Saving Time" occurs in the 5th occurrence of the Sunday of March which is false because it is the 4th occurrence. [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481(v=vs.85).aspx).

So when I am doing :

```
void findDate(int year, SYSTEMTIME systemTime)
{
    struct tm timestr;
    int occ = 0;
    bool found = false;

    timestr.tm_year = year - 1900;
    timestr.tm_mon = systemTime.wMonth - 1;
    timestr.tm_mday = 0;
    timestr.tm_hour = systemTime.wHour;
    timestr.tm_min = systemTime.wMinute;
    timestr.tm_sec = systemTime.wSecond;
    timestr.tm_isdst = 0;

    while((timestr.tm_mday <= 31 && !found)) {
        timestr.tm_mday += 1;
        time_t standard = mktime(&timestr);
        struct tm * temp = localtime(&standard);
        if(temp->tm_wday == systemTime.wDayOfWeek) {
           occ++;
        }

        if(occ >= sysemTime.wDay) {
             found = true;
             printf("\n\nFound: %s", asctime( &timestr ));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 // Get the timezone info.
 TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION TimeZoneInfo;
 GetTimeZoneInformation( &TimeZoneInfo );
 DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION TimeZoneInfoDyn;

 printf("\n\nStandardDate %d wDay%d wDayOfWeek%d %d %d %d", TimeZoneInfo.StandardDate.wMonth, TimeZoneInfo.StandardDate.wDay, TimeZoneInfo.StandardDate.wDayOfWeek, TimeZoneInfo.StandardDate.wHour, TimeZoneInfo.StandardDate.wMinute, TimeZoneInfo.StandardDate.wSecond);
 printf("\nDaylightDate %d wDay%d wDayOfWeek%d %d %d %d", TimeZoneInfo.DaylightDate.wMonth, TimeZoneInfo.DaylightDate.wDay, TimeZoneInfo.DaylightDate.wDayOfWeek, TimeZoneInfo.DaylightDate.wHour, TimeZoneInfo.DaylightDate.wMinute, TimeZoneInfo.DaylightDate.wSecond);

 findDate(2017, TimeZoneInfo.StandardDate);
 findDate(2018, TimeZoneInfo.DaylightDate);
 getchar();
 return 0;

}
```

It displays :

```
Found: Sun Oct 29 03:00:00 2017
Found: Sun Apr 01 03:00:00 2018
```

Instead of :

```
Found: Sun Oct 29 03:00:00 2017
Found: Sun Mar 25 03:00:00 2018
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use correct tags! C is not C++.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, but as my compiler is C++, all ideas or solutions regarding C or C++ languages are welcome.

Comment: C is not a subset of C++. Just using C functions does not qualify for the C tag.

Comment: disagree, if your compiler is that old, you wont be able to use C++11 or beyond stuff, if you write C++ you cant/shouldnt use VLAs, ...etc... it does matter

Comment: @sdespont: This is a Q&A and we expect one language per question. Not every C thing works in C++, and when you bring idioms into the mix the best solutions may/will vary _wildly_. So tag the language you're _actually_ using. If one day you switch to C you can ask a new question and find out whether the answer is the same.

Comment: Add includes to your code to make a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The "W. Europe Standard Time" in the registery says that the "Daylight Saving Time" occurs in the 5th occurance of the sunday of March which is false because it is the 4th occurance.

From the documentation quoted in the linked answer:

> (1 to 5, where 5 indicates the final occurrence during the month if that day of the week does not occur 5 times).

So it is not false.

Furthermore, in your loop you increment `tm_mday` and `occ` *before* checking whether you've already reached the desired day. If you were on it to start with, you'll overshoot.

By the way, `sysemTime` is misspelt.

Comment: Excellent.. nice guess :D